# c++: noskipws delays end of file detection for some datatypes

Tags: c++

From what I know about `noskipws`, it disables the skipping of white spaces. So one needs to take white spaces by some char in their program if they want to work with `noskipws`. I try to set the `cin` to `eof` condition by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> for Windows). But if I use a `char` or `string` input, then the stream is set to end of file with a single input. However, if I use some other data type, then it requires me to press the combination twice. If I remove the `noskipws` request, everything else works fine. The following code explains the problem more precisely:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cin >> noskipws; //noskipws request
    int number; //If this int is replaced with char then it works fine
    while (!cin.bad()) {
        cout << "Enter ctrl + D (ctrl + Z for windows) to set cin stream to end of file " << endl;
        cin >> number;
        if (cin.eof()) {
            break; // Reached end of file
        }
    }
    cout << "End of file encountered" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Why is `cin` behaving this way? Although it wouldn't be able to put the input into the `int` variable, it at least should set flags to `eof` immediately as it receives the request. Why does it take a second input even after the user presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>?

Comment: Could you clearly say what input you are providing to produce the unexpected behaviour with this code

Comment: I press ctrl + Z in console and the console requires one more input

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Equivalent to ^D (in bash) for cmd.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe)

Comment: How is that duplicate of [Equivalent to ^D (in bash) for cmd.exe?](https://superuser.com/questions/291224/equivalent-to-d-in-bash-for-cmd-exe), actually everything works fine on removing noskipws ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. If I immediately type Ctrl Z (or F6) with this code, the program ends immediately.

Comment: Seems you need to give more details. I can´t reproduce the effect. Neither with clang-900.0.37 on MacOS 10.12 nor on Debian Stitch with gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 nor on Raspian with gcc version 4.9.2.

Answer (score 0):

When `noskipws` is used your code is responsible for extraction of white spaces. When you reading int it fails since white space is encountered.

See [an example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vQgof4xjfEaXq2cM):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>

#define NOSKIPWS

#define InputStreamFlag(x) cout << setw(14) << "cin." #x "() = " << boolalpha << cin.x() << '\n'

using namespace std;

int main()
{
#ifdef NOSKIPWS
    cin >> noskipws;
    char ch;
#endif
    int x;
    while (cin >> x) {
        cout << x << ' ';
#ifdef NOSKIPWS
        while (isspace(cin.peek()))
        {
            cin >> ch;
        }
#endif
    }
    cout << endl;

    InputStreamFlag(eof);
    InputStreamFlag(fail);
    InputStreamFlag(bad);
    InputStreamFlag(good) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or [visual studio](http://rextester.com/RZB15953).